# How do I ignore specific words in a search and replace regex?

Tags: regular-expression

I am using this working regex
`:%s/\( to\)\([a-z]\)/\1 \2/c`
to replace `tothem` with `to them` and `tohim` with `to him`.
But I do not want to look at words like `together`, `tone`, `tonal`, etc

I tried something like this
`:%s/\(\?\!together|tone|tonal\)\( to\)\([a-z]\)/\1 \2/c`
but I clearly have the syntax wrong.

Comment: `:h perl-patterns`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to use with `\?\!` is an adaptation of Perl's zero with lookahead which doesn't exist in vim. The equivalent in vim is [`:h /\@!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%40%21), you could use it this way:

```
:%s/\(to\)\(gether\|nal\|ne\)\@!\([a-z]\)/\1 \3

    \(to\)                                          match "to"
                             \@!                    not followed by
          \(gether\|nal\|ne\)                       "gether", "nal", "ne"
                                \([a-z]\)           and capture the next letter
```

However to me that doesn't look very efficient because you need to write the list of the valid values.

Maybe you could use `set spell` to highlight the wrong words, navigate to the matches with `]s` and then run `:s/\(to\)\([a-z]\)/\1 \2` (which you can repeat with `@:` if needed.

Comment: I use neovim and there's \zs and \ze that works as lookahead and behind. Is it not available on vim ?

Comment: @JustKhaithang `\zs` and `\ze` also exists in vim it's just that here I'm not sure how to use them efficiently to achieve OP's goal. But if you have a solution using them don't hesitate to post an answer: The more diversity in the answer the more their is to learn for everybody :)

Comment: @Satox, ideally what I would do is use a dictionary file, lots of words to ignore, and the `:h /\@!` syntax. Using `set spell` wasn't really an option becasue of the size of the file, but a very good idea

Comment: @Kes Depending on the size of the dictionary maybe you could built the regex via vimscript: Reading the dictionary, concatenating it into a string `\(word1\|word2\|word3\)` and then running the substitution but I'm not sure about the performances. To do it maybe `sed` + a shell script would be easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

If those two (tothem and tohim) are the only patterns then you can modify the regexp to be more specific i.e. to only match those two specific patterns :

```
:%s/\( to\)\(him\|them\)/\1 \2/c
```

Another way  :

```
:%s/\( to\)\(.\?..m\)/\1 \2/c
```

The regex in the second group is looking for a pattern that has either 2 or 3 character followed by the character `m`.

The more the merrier :

```
:%s/\( to\)\(.\?h[ie]m\)/\1 \2/c
```

Comment: thank you :) That is a nice way of doing it. For this case there were so many different joined words in a large file that a dictionary would, I think, have been necessary.